# How can i get manager name from AD in php?

Tags: php, active-directory

Now, i'm doing to connect my website to AD use ldap and get data from user logon but my problem is when user logon and i need to get manager name of user i get manager name by call `$entries[0]["manager"][0]` it's show data like this `CN=rosie,OU=AllUser,DC=xyz,DC=local` i need to get only manager name that is 'rosie' but i don't know to get it, please help

this my code

```
$ldap_host ="servername";
$ldap_port = "port";
$ldap_dn = "OU=AllUser,DC=abc,DC=local";
$ldap_usr_dom = '@abc.local';
$ldap_it_group = "IT";
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host,$ldap_port) or die("Could not connect to ".$ldap_host);
$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password) or die("cant bind");
if($bind) {
    $filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=".$user."))";
    $attr = array("manager");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    ldap_unbind($ldap);
    for ($i=0; $i<$entries["count"]; $i++) {
        echo "Manager is: ". $entries[0]["manager"][0]."<p>";
    }
```

Comment: ok, a question... why not just strip out everything but the `rosie` value?

Comment: it's a name of manager. I need only CN of manager

Comment: that is what I was suggesting... _obviously_ `rosie` would be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is a totally horrible way of doing it... doing regex would be better, but this is a quick hack job for ya, until the regex guys come around to provide the expression.

```
$manager = str_replace('CN=','',strstr($entries[0]["manager"][0],',',true));
echo "Manager is: ". $manager ."<p>";
```

Comment: Yes it's horrible i'm new for do AD with ldap i don't know how to do it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: php+AD core code needs a serious amount of attention from the php crew. suppose few folks use it so why, can be my only guess. the only time i have ever used it was screwing around with powerschool. anyway, the above does appear to work on my end, so hope it works out for ya.